# How to handle several parallel request in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS for taking screenshot inside NodeJS but it can't handle multiple request from users. The problem is when several users send request concurrently they get same result.

This is the code I'm using:

```
var http = require('http');
var phantom = require('phantom');
var url, img;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
  url = req.url;
  url = url.replace('/', '');
  url = url.trim();
  if (!(url == 'favicon.ico')) {
    console.log(url);
    phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
      ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1024, height: 768 }).then(function() {
          page.open('http://' + url + '/').then(function(status) {
            console.log(status);
            page.property('onLoadFinished').then(function() {
              if (!(status == 'success')) {
                res.write('<html><body><h2>' + status + ' : ' + url + ' is not correct url!</h2></body></html>');
                res.end();
                page.close();
              } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  page.renderBase64('jpeg').then(function(img) {
                    res.write('<html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + img + '"/></body></html>');
                    res.end();
                    page.close();
                  });
                }, 4000);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

Comment: *"they get different result"* - this isn't necessarily bad. Are you sure they need to get the same result? How do the two results differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `var url, img;` outside the scope of `http` request, meaning they're being shared by different requests (one request might change it while a previous one was still processing it), which is probably what's causing the issue. Move those declarations inside the request handler:

```
// var url, img; // << move this
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var url, img; // << here
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
```